# React Native CFBundleIdentifier does not exist

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When I try to `react-native run ios`, I am getting CFBundleIdentifier issue.

An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.53.0

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the build folder on your iOS project and then build again. I've resolved this problem with this solution a lot of times.

```
$ rm -rf ios/build/
$ react-native run-ios
```

If this doesn't work your issue could be related with another problem. You can take a look to this [discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308) on GitHub.

Comment: Mateo, your discussion link is broken.  Do you have an updated link to that discussion?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

This issue could occurs if project missing **config.h** file,

To update **config.h** file,

1. Close your **xCode**.
2. Open **Terminal**,
3. Go to your project's root folder and enter (**glog version may vary .. mine is 0.3.5**)

   cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/
4. Now run the configure script:

   ./configure
5. Now run the configure script:

   make
6. Open **xCode** and try to run your app.